# How to get the number of cluster nodes in onTrigger function at run time?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a nifi cluster with 6 nodes and I want to do some load balance in my custom processor's `onTrigger` function:

```
@Override
public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, final ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {

}
```

How can I get the number of nodes in this  function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing load balancing with in a processor. The processor's job is to take one or more flow files, operate on them, and produce one or more flow files.

There are built in mechanisms to perform load balancing across the cluster:

https://blogs.apache.org/nifi/entry/load-balancing-across-the-cluster

Comment: This processor is the source of all flow files. It listens to a message queue, and I need it generate flow file. So it should do load balance itself.

Comment: The processor should just produce flow files and place them in the queue, that queue should then be a load balanced connection (referenced in blog above) which would do the load balancing to the rest of the nodes.